# Correlation of a vector generated and its one-period lag, both generated using AR(1) data

Tags: probability, probability-theory, time-series

> Suppose that $C_0$ is $100$ and $\{e_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. standard normal random variables. We generate $C_t=C_{t-1}+e_t$ for $t\geq 1$ and set
>   $$
> x_t=C_t^2-C^2_{t-1},\quad z_t=C^2_{t-1}-C^2_{t-2}\quad\text{for}\quad t\geq 2.
> $$
>   For fixed $T\geq 2$, let us define $X=(x_2,\ldots,x_T)$ and $Z=(z_2,\ldots,z_T)$. How do we show that the sample correlation between $X$ and $Z$
>   $$
> \rho_T\equiv\frac{\sum_{t=2}^T(x_t-\bar{X})(z_t-\bar{Z})}{\sqrt{\sum_{t=2}^T(x_t-\bar{X})^2\sum_{t=2}^T(z_t-\bar{Z})^2}}
> $$
>   converges in probability to $0$ as $T\to\infty$?

This is a claim contained in Nelson and Startz 1990 article in Journal of Business. I can't prove it nor do I understand the intuition behind this. I have however written a simple Matlab script below that seems consistent with the claim. Thank you very much for your help. (If you have the Parallel Computing Toolbox, you can use `parfor` for the inner loop.)

```
clc; clear;
tic;
L = [10,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]; % length of AR process
l = length(L);
results = zeros(l,1);
n = 10000;                         % no. of rep's per length choice
c0 = 100;                          % initial value

for i = 1:l
    T = L(i);                      % current length
    temp1 = zeros(n,1);            % store correlations for the n reps
    for j = 1:n
        e = randn(T,1);            % shocks
        c = filter(1,[1 -1],e,c0); % AR(1) process initial c0
        d = c.^2;                  % store squares of c's       
        x = d(2:T) - d(1:T-1);     % x_t=c_t^2-c_{t-1}^2
        z = [d(1) - c0^2;x(1:T-2)];% z_t=x_{t-1}
        temp1(j) = corr(x,z);      % correlation for rep j
    end
    results(i) = mean(temp1);      % average correlation across n reps
end
plot(L,results);
toc;
```

Comment: You seem to define $X$ and $Z$ as vectors, so what is meant by $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Z}$ in your formulas? (they look like scalars).

Comment: $\bar{X}=\sum_{t=2}^Tx_t$ and similarly $\bar{Z}$. I thought the notation was quite standard. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Do you mean a time average and dividing by $T-1$? So $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=2}^Tx_t$? Otherwise, I have never seen overline notation to represent a sum, I cannot imagine it being "standard."

Comment: Temporarily ignoring your definition of $\rho_T$, I observe that $x_t = e_t^2 + 2e_tC_{t-1}$ and $z_t=e_{t-1}^2+2e_{t-1}C_{t-2}$ and $E[x_tz_t] = E[e_t^2]E[e_{t-1}^2] = E[x_t]E[z_t]$, so they are indeed uncorrelated.

Comment: @Michael Sorry I did mean to divide by $T-1$ for both $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer that just looks at corellations. We have: 
\begin{align} 
x_t &= e_t^2 + 2e_tC_{t-1} \\
z_t &= e_{t-1}^2 + 2e_{t-1}C_{t-2} 
\end{align} 
First note that $E[x_t]=E[z_t]=1$ for all $t \geq 2$. Now we show that $\{x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots\}$ are pairwise uncorrelated.  Fix $t>n\geq 2$. Then: 
$$ E[x_tx_n] = E[(e_t^2 + 2e_tC_{t-1})(e_n^2 + 2e_nC_{n-1})] = E[e_t^2e_n^2] = E[x_t]E[x_n] $$ 
and so these are indeed pairwise uncorellated.  Likewise, $\{z_2, z_3, z_4, \ldots\}$ are pairwise uncorellated.

Notice that:
$$ x_tz_t = e_t^2e_{t-1}^2 + 2e_t^2e_{t-1}C_{t-2} + 2e_tC_{t-1}e_{t-1}^2 + 4e_te_{t-1}C_{t-1}C_{t-2}  $$
So: 
$$ E[x_tz_t] = E[e_t^2]E[e_{t-1}^2] = 1 = E[x_t]E[z_t] $$
So $x_t$ and $z_t$ are in fact uncorrelated for each $t$.  Now look at correlations between $x_tz_t$ and $x_nz_n$ for $t \neq n$.  I think that they are uncorrelated whenever $|n-t|\geq 2$.

---

Pairwise uncorellated means the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances. 
The mean of $\overline{X}_T$ is 1 for all $T$, but its variance does *not* converge to zero as $T\rightarrow\infty$.  But I think the variance of $\frac{1}{T^a}\overline{X}_T$ converges to 0 for any $a>0$. I suspect the end result holds because the variance of the numerator in $\rho_T$ grows much more slowly than the variance of the denominator as $T\rightarrow\infty$.